# Trouble displaying long columns in psql in tabular format

Tags: postgresql, psql

Issue displaying long columns in psql because of using the tabular format in psqlrc

psql version: 15.2
postgres version: 15.2

Here is the error:

```
❯ get_output
Enter a username:
test
Enter output:
fdlkjflajslfdjasljflsjfla
The result is: Timing
Expanded
Line
Border
Pager
Target
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│
├─────────────────────────────────────┤
│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
(1
```

I have tried configuring below values on `psqlrc`:

```
\x auto
\set HISTFILE ~/.psql_history/ :DBNAME
\set VERBOSITY verbose
\set HISTCONTROL ignoredups
\set COMP_KEYWORD_CASE preserve-lower

\pset linestyle unicode
\pset border 2
\pset pager off
\setenv LESS '-S'
```

Note: I am having no issues when psqlrc is disabled, but I would like the results in tabular format and made few changes to `psqlrc`